# Google Sheets REGEXEXTRACT numeric value from string with double quotes

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this string in a google sheet cell B1:

```
{
  "schedules":[],
  "name": "10000 Stitches",
  "report": { 
    "printtitle": false, 
    "margin":"normal", "notes":false,
    "format":"pdf",
    "horizontal_alignment":"CENTER",
    "vertical_alignment":"TOP",
    "scale":"2",
    "filesettings":"individual",
    "pagenum":false,
    "sheetnames":false,
    "fzc":false,
    "layout":"landscape",
    "sheets": [
      {
        "sheetid":"287088559",
        "active":true,
        "filename":"",
        "cellrange":null
      }
    ],
    "size":"letter",
    "globalfilename":"",
    "gridlines":false,
    "fzr":false
  },
  "active":false,
  "id":3,
  "email": { 
    "body":"<p>attached</p>",
    "text":"",
    "subject": "{%'10000 Stitches'!B1%} payout report for {%'10000 Stitches'!B2%}",
    "to":"{%'10000 Stitches'!B6%}",
    "cc":"",
    "bcc":"",
    "fromname":"EPM Operations",
    "savetodrive":true,
    "drivefolderid":"129szEEvSqGa5D8fi6BVyMEp0bvCmYvTk",
    "bodytype":"html"
  }
}
```

which I am trying to extract the numeric value from...   `"id":3,`

I have tried this regular expression (among others)

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B1,"id"":(.*)")`
```

but keep getting the error:
`Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "id":(.*)" does not match text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value "".`

I'm not sure if my handling of the double quotes, the colon, the comma or the wildcard syntax for the numeric data is wrong.  I've studied so many stackoverflow threads but am spinning my wheels.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Rafa for cleaning up my post.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B1,"""id"":(\d)")*1
```

The way to escape double quotes `"` is by adding extra double quotes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  QUESTION:  Why the *1 at the end?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I see that the *1 converts the extracted result to a number.  QUESTION:  "id":# could be variable in length - how do I ensure it pulls all of the numbers up until the "," at the end of that part of the string?

Comment: Answered my own question:  (\d*) captures complete ID number.

Comment: *"Answered my own question..."* That is great. Please read more about [RE2 regular expression syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt). Thank you for taking the time to accept. Glad I could help.